# Groovy - How to serialize an object into a string

Tags: groovy

How to serialize an object into a string

below is the .net code for serializing an object into a string

```
String sampleEntity= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity))
```

same I need it in groovy? please suggest

Answer (score 2):

Assuming entity is some object or list of objects, the easiest way IMO is:

```
import groovy.json.*
class Person { // this is a sample object, like entity in your example
   String name
}
def json = JsonOutput.toJson([ new Person(name: 'John'), new Person(name: 'Max') ])

println json​
// output (string): [{"name":"John"},{"name":"Max"}]
```

If you need to customize the output (like fiddle with exact format of dates or something), you should use JsonGenerator Instead. It has a builder that will allow to do this fine grained setup. Since its a kind of beyond the scope of the question, I'll just provide a link to the [relevant chapter of documentation](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html#_customizing_output)